# sql server select statement for 3 tables using join

Tags: sql, sql-server

below is the link of my problem please 
help me to find the solution.

http://forums.asp.net/post/5682629.aspx

[image]

Comment: If you can't be bothered to re-type or copy/paste the question here, don't expect anyone to bother answering.

Comment: Please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this query :

```
select top 3 Package_Title, DurationInDays,Package_Image_1, Adult_Price , 
    STUFF((Select themes.theme + ',' From package_theme 
        inner join themes on themeid = package_theme.theme
        Where package_theme.package = packages.Package_ID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')     As theme
from packages 
inner join  rates on rates.package = packages.Package_ID
```

Comment: almost there but check my updated question.

Comment: ok just a while to get update your query

Comment: i update my query check it now. your desire output available now.

Comment: i update my query check it now. your desire output available now.

if you like. check and give me upvote pls.

Comment: if you satisfied with my answer. pls give me upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You have four tables and you are joining only 3 tables.
You are trying to use the column name which is in `themes` table, but you have not defined it the `FROM` clause.

You need to always specify `n-1` joining condition for `n` tables.

Add one more join condition and your query will execute without errors

Answer (score 0):

I think that this query will help you. but I think that you may need to change the table names because there is some table name conflict too in your query. Improve the table name format and column names. The problem with your query is that you haven't joined the themes table and you was trying to access its column.

```
select top 3 A.Package_Title, A.DurationInDays, Package_Image_1,
B.Adult_Price,D.Theme from packages A 
inner join rates B on B.Package = A.Package_ID 
inner join package_theme C on C.package=A.Package_ID
inner join themes D on D.Theme_ID = C.theme
```

Comment: isn't this basically the same answer as the one posted. ??